# Darcula dark theme for Eclipse

Tags: ubuntu, theme, eclipse, ide

I wonder if there is a way to use Android Studio Darcula theme in Eclipse? I am trying to make Eclipse look a little bit like AS. So far I have made changes to the editor window and I have no idea how to tackle the rest of window frames etc. Any ideas how to change colour of window frames without affecting rest of the Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

There is an [Eclipse Color Theme Plugin](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/) that might be able to help you :)

Comment: This is great but I want to change window frames to be dark too. Thanks for the link. These themes are great!

Comment: Glad to help :) I don't know how to change window frames though. Maybe its not possible. I think Eclipse is using GTK to create window frames, that makes use of your desktop environment functions to draw them.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in Alko's answer, use the [Eclipse Color Theme Plugin](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/) to theme the main text field.

In order to theme all the other views (package explorer, console and so on), you need to use an Eclipse Theme. Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Appearance`. There you can select an Eclipse Theme.

I personally use the [Dark Juno](http://blog.rogerdudler.com/post/38229973729/dark-juno-a-dark-ui-theme-for-eclipse-4) theme.

Finally, you may see some things still aren't themed (like the project names when using EGit). You will need to edit the colors for these things manually. For example, to get the project names in the colors of the Dark Juno theme, you will need to go `Colors and Fonts` under `Appearance` and edit `Uncommited Change (Background)` and `Uncommited Change (Foreground)`.

Comment: I mentioned this answer in my related SOF question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134001/eclipse-egit-with-dark-background-still-has-black-text

Answer (score 2):

I found that [Moonrise UI](http://guari.github.io/eclipse-ui-theme/) theme is the best choice for me.

It's very nice and it works better than Dark Juno.

Comment: I switched to Aptana Studio, no plugins required.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to accomplish this and it works across all platforms, is the [Darkest Theme plugin for eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme).

Use that with the [Dracula eclipse color preferences](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=12886), and you have a very good dark theme that resembles the Darcula settings in Intellij.